# Any crypto exchanges with one-cancel-others order type?

Tags: exchange, cryptocurrency

I have an Interactive Broker account to trade regular stocks. They have a One Cancel Others order type that allows me to put both a stop loss (SL) and take profit (TP) order on a single position.

Is there any crypto exchange that allow me to do the same on my spot position? I used Kraken but they don't offer such feature.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binance offers an OCO order, please have a look at this reference: https://www.binance.com/en-BH/support/faq/what-is-an-oco-one-cancels-the-other-order-and-how-to-use-it-360032605831

> A One-Cancels-the-Other (OCO) order combines one stop limit order and
> one limit order, where if one is fully or partially fulfilled, the
> other is canceled. An OCO order on Binance consists of a stop-limit
> order and a limit order with the same order quantity. Both orders must
> be either buy or sell orders. If you cancel one of the orders, the
> entire OCO order pair will be canceled.